# Remove any terraform resources from aws

Tags: terraform

A couple of months ago I played around with `terraform init` > `apply` from a github repo containing many terraform modules.

Didn't work as promised. Deleted the repo and forgot about it.

Now giving the repo another try results in many `xyz already exists` errors upon `terraform init` > `apply`. e.g.

```
...
error creating DynamoDB Table: ResourceInUseException:
Error creating Cognito User Pool Domain: InvalidParameterException: Domain already associated
etc..
..
.
```

And indeed I see e.g. `aws iam list-users` returns a User created a couple of months ago and having the same name as the project.

Tried `destroy` to no avail.

Searching for a solution return lengthy posts about atomic approaches requiring importing resource `Id's` etc. I want to start over. From scratch.

Does getting rid of terraform tests require me to https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke?

Comment: If you didn't save the Terraform state file from your previous runs, and you just want to delete everything in the AWS account, then `aws-nuke` is probably the easiest route you can take. In the future you should save your Terraform state file, at least until you run `terraform destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

aws Nuke will remove all resources from the AWS account, do you have access to the terraform.tfstate file? if so you will be able to run terraform destroy.
you can also check for terraform.tfstate error or remote file.
you can also run terraform import command with the assets ID.then you will be able to run terraform destroy for removing all resources.